# Click load more button jooble selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to web scrape this [page](https://jooble.org/SearchResult?date=8&p=5&rgns=New%20York%2C%20NY&ukw=software) and I'm looking for a way to click the load more button using selenium python. I have tried with these codes

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Load more").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div/button/span').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div/button').click()
```

but none of the above have worked the main code,My alternative solution was using the scroll like this...

```
def infinite(driver):
    
    scroll_pause_time = 10

    # Get scroll height
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:

        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)

        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div/button').click()#This doesn't work
        except:
            print('No button')
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.HOME)
        print('yeah!')
        if new_height == last_height:
            # If heights are the same it will exit the function
            break
        last_height = new_height
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `modal pop-up window`, that you can click on Yes or No or to `X` button.

Once that is `clicked`, you will have to scroll all the way down to the button and the Selenium can see the Load more button, eventually, you'd be able to click on it.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://jooble.org/SearchResult?date=8&p=5&rgns=New%20York%2C%20NY&ukw=software")
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Close']"))).click()
except:
    pass

driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Load more']/.."))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```